# How can I speed up my terminal execution of the make command generated by CMake?

Tags: command-line, compiling, make, cmake

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS**, and have the snap version of **CMake (3.19.4)** installed. I am using it to build an app written in C++.

When I build my solution in the terminal, the make command takes forever to execute. But when I build the project in the **CLion IDE** that is using **CMake (3.17.3)**, the entire process is done within seconds.

What could be causing the slowdown? How could I speed up the terminal compilation?

(I had this problem when using the apt version (3.16.3) as well)

Comment: Maybe nothing had changed, so the second make run did nothing but check for what needed recompilation (nothing?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use all available CPU cores for parallel builds:

```
cd build
make -j$(nproc)
```

or just execute `nproc` once and use that number directly:

```
nproc
8
cd build
make -j8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ninja build system (`sudo apt install ninja-build` is required).

Prepare the build:

```sh
cmake -G Ninja -B build
```

Followed by the actual Ninja build (no need to provide `-j` anymore, because Ninja will do the heavy lifting for you and run parallel build jobs by default):

```sh
cmake --build ./build
```

To build only a specific target use (**by default** it tries to build *all targets*):

```sh
cmake --build ./build --target your_target_name
```

Helpfully this helps!